# What are blood group determinants?

Tags: immunology, hematology, terminology, antigen

I am trying to understand if they are the same as the blood antigens. The books I have tried to read say something about them being the antigens on the surface of the red blood cell.

Answer (score 0):

Blood group A expresses A antigens and anti-B antibodies etc etc, see the next figure:

[image: abo]

Taken from the wikipedia entry on [blood groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABO_blood_group_system).

Answer (score 0):

In immunology, determinant is another name for [epitope](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epitope) (the portion of an antigen recognized by a BCR/Ab or TCR).